# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group_Status definitions

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I look at the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group_Status definition and it doesn't define what are the valid values for statusId. I have some image templates that are bad and want disable them so they can't be used. How do I disable a flex or image template.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your question, these are the status for images:

> - 1 Active
> - 2 Inactive
> - 4 Deprecated

Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the status from your images, you can only delete them, follow these steps for it:

**1 Retrieve images:**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups

Method: Get
```

You will get a result like this:

```
{
"accountId": 123123
"createDate": "2016-01-25T17:53:11-04:00"
"id": 222333
"name": "TestImage"
"parentId": null
"publicFlag": 0
"statusId": 1
"transactionId": null
"userRecordId": 99999
"globalIdentifier": "f2d50dfg-2340-4c21-9345d-3074141128c5ec"
}
```

**2 Delete Image**

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/222333/deleteObject

Method: Get
```

If you only wish to change the status from your images for any reason, submit a ticket to SoftLayer for it please.